# Javascript replace text after an underscore

Tags: javascript, regex, toggle

I am trying to replace some text after an underscore in a filename.

Example filename: `FileName_true.png`. I need to change it to `FileName_false.png`.

Basically, i have an image that i want to change when you click on it. (color to black and white and vice versa).  I thought about using a toggle in JQuery but i wasn't sure that i could do it with like 5 images without duplicating the code 5 times.

My thinking was to create a function that uses a regex to capture the 'true' or 'false in the file name of the image you clicked on and replace it with the alternate.

What are your thoughts on accomplishing this?  I would like this done in PHP if possible, but if not then JavaScript/JQuery.  Thanks for any help!  And let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filename = filename.replace('_true','_false');
```

neither jQuery nor regexp necessary

```
<img src="FileName_true.png"
onclick="this.src=(this.src.indexOf('_true')!=-1)?this.src.replace('true','false'):this.src.replace('false','true')" />
```

is what I could come up with at this late hour

To do this in php would be plain silly and would need a cookie

Comment: Thanks do much...i'll give that a try.  Now, would there be a way to store the new file name in a variable or hidden input so i can pass it through on a form.  The image is inside of a form and the file name is getting pulled from a database (via PHP) and i want to be able to save the new current state of the file name in the database when you submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by mplungjan is great, but let me suggest some alternatives.  Image swaps are best done with a [sprite](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+sprite), so that there is never any delay switching between the images.  Put both versions of the image side by side in a single file.  Set that image to be the background of a div, and adjust the background position to display one or the other image.

Suppose "pic1_bw_color_sprite.png" was a 75x75 color image, with a 75x75 b/w image below it, making the final image 75px wide and 150px high.  Set up your css like this:

```
#pic1
{
    background-image: url(pic1_bw_color_sprite.png);
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}
#pic1.bw
{
    background-position: 0px -75px;
}
```

Then some simple jQuery to make it all work:

```
$("#pic1").click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass("bw");
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/B7esz/

As far as duplicating the code, that is one thing that jQuery is very good at avoiding.  Just use a selector that includes every class that needs the behavior:

```
$("#pic1,#pic2,#pic3,#pic4").click(...);
// or
$(".bwSwap").click(...);
```

To store the current state in the form so that you can update your database, you need to get a reference to your form element, then set the `value` property (or `.val()` in jQuery).

```
$("#pic1").click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass("bw");
    $("#pic1isBW").val($(this).hasClass("bw"));
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks! That sounds like it may be a better option.  Although i'm storing the filename in a database so it can be referenced later.  Do you have any ideas on my comment on mplungjan's answer on how to save the new filename to the database?

Comment: @Ryan - To get a value in the form, just populate the element's `value` property.  I've added an example in my answer.

Comment: +1 for the sprite. I have to remember that. It is a little more work initially since you have to change all images you want to toggle to sprites.