# Change image source on mouseover of parent div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent, mouseover

I have an image and rollover image. Using jQuery or CSS, I want to show/hide the rollover image when the onmousemove/onmouseout event happen on the parent div (containing the image).

How can I do it?

Edit:  HTML posted below by request.  Not relevant to the question, but as an FYI HTML is built on a 30 column fluid grid.

Upon hover of the top div (row-fluid) the image (image.png) should change to a different source image (imagehover.png).

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="padding-top:1em">
            <div class="span4">
              //Random content
            </div>
            <div class="span8 offset1">
              //Random content
            </div>
            <div class="span9 offset3">
              <ul>
                <li>//Random content</li>
                <li>//Random content</li>
                <li>//Random content</li>
             </ul>
            </div>
            <img src='../../images/image.png>
<div>
```

Comment: Posting the corresponding HTML will help

Comment: Use a sprite as background image and change background position in a `:hover` rule:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614430/javascript-replace-text-after-an-underscore/5614760#5614760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I used elements of others' comments and answers to create a hybrid: a sprite, totally CSS solution.  I find this to be optimal.

Per @gilly3 "Image swaps are best done with a sprite, so that there is never any delay switching between the images. Put both versions of the image side by side in a single file. Set that image to be the background of a div, and adjust the background position to display one or the other image."  For this example, I will use a 96px (height) by 27px (width) sprite, using my em values.

In HTML replace img line with:

```
<div class="sprite-image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.sprite-image {
{
background-image: url(../../images/image.png);
height: 3.7em;
width: 27px;
}

.row-fluid:hover .sprite-image
{
background-position: 0px -3.7em;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You want to do something like this: `full_path_to_css parent:hover child`

```
full_path_to_css parent:hover child {
  styles for your item
}
```

eg:

html (the div.img can be anything):

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

css:

```
div.​parent​ {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
div.img {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}

div.parent:hover div.img {
  background-color:green;
}​
```

if you want to test check here: http://jsfiddle.net/NicosKaralis/kd6wy/

just to remember, the `div` with `img` class can be any element, doesn't need to be `div` and you can change the css styles as you wish, the only thing you need to watch is the `parent:hover child`

**EDIT**

Just to clarify one thing: the item with `:hover` is the parent on witch you want to detect the hover action, and the `child` is the item on witch you want to change the css rules

**EDIT AGAIN**

```
<div id="parent" class="row-fluid" style="padding-top:1em">
        <div class="span4">
          //Random content
        </div>
        <div class="span8 offset1">
          //Random content
        </div>
        <div class="span9 offset3">
          <ul>
            <li>//Random content</li>
            <li>//Random content</li>
            <li>//Random content</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <img class="child" src='../../images/image.png>
<div>
```

on your code you will need:

```
div#parent.row-fluid img.child {
  display:none;
}
div#parent.row-fluid:hover img.child {
  display:block;
}
```

this will make your image only show up if the mouse is over your div

Comment: Question does not include background-image or background-color change, rather an img src change.  Can this CSS be adopted for that?

Comment: With the 'Edit Again' I'm missing how to have 1 image before hover, and another after hover.  This seems to just display an image upon hover, not change the source.

Comment: you can add 2 images and hide one or another depending on what do you want

Comment: Ah I see.  It looks like there should be the additional/edited following markup.

HTML added:
<img class="childhover" src='../../images/imagehover.png>

CSS added and edited:
div#parent.row-fluid img.child {
  display:block;
}
div#parent.row-fluid:hover img.child {
  display:none;
}
div#parent.row-fluid img.childhover {
  display:none;
}
div#parent.row-fluid:hover img.childhover {
  display:block;
}

Comment: Wow! I had no idea you could do that with just CSS, and I have a lot of CSS experience (at least I thought I did!). I was waiting for a JS only solution to pop up. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Should just be as easy as attaching a mouseover and mouseout event handlers to the parent div and then manipulating the containing img element.

```
var rolloverImage = ...
var origImage = ...
$("#parentDivId")
       .mouseover(function() {
          $("#parentDivId img").attr("src", rolloverImage)
       })
       .mouseout(function() {
          $("#parentDivId img").attr("src", origImage)
       })
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having any html to test with, this is just something I thought up in my head.  Not sure if it will work or not, but I don't see why it wouldn't.

```
$('div').mouseenter(function() {
    var image = $('img', this);

    $(image.attr('src', 'new-image-src.jpg');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    var image = $('img', this);

    $(image).attr('src', 'old-image-src.jpg');
});
```

Comment: How does this specify the div element for mouseenter rather than img element?

Comment: updated my code, misread your question, didn't see the part about having it happen on hover of div.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('div.row-fluid').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
}, function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'http://www.placekitten.com/100/100');
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mpmqm/)**

Comment: This looks like it will work.  About to test, a couple questions to ensure implementation is correct.

Div class must be unique, otherwise this will apply to all row-fluid divs correct?  So if div contains multiple classes, i.e. <div class="row-fluid hoverclass"> does the code become?:

$('div.row-fluid.hoverclass').hover(function() {

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to "show/hide the rollover image"

```
#parentDiv > img {
  display: none;
}
#parentDiv:hover > img {
  display: block;
}
```

The `>` allows you to select `img` tags that are the direct descendents of `#parentDiv` (I gave the outer div that ID). Then we're just setting a different style for it on regular and hover states.

Comment: The img src needs to change, not a style on the img element.